# Deficiency of a subspace

Tags: functional-analysis

What is meant by deficiency of a subspace in an infinite dimensional normed linear space? It is given that " by Hahn Banach theorem,there exists a non zero linear continuous functional on the space whose null space has deficiency 1."

Comment: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Deficiency_subspace may be of help. I apologize if you have already seen this page.

Comment: A.K.A. co-dimension $1.$ A vector subspace $U$ has co-dimension $1$ iff it is a proper subspace and there exists a vector $v$ such that the vector subspace  generated by $U\cup \{v\}$ is the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y$ be a subspace of a vector space $X$, then the deficiency of $Y$ is the dimension of the quotient space $X/Y$.